# Как сделать прокрутку вниз в TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, прокрутка

Иногда, при заполнении TextView, текст выходит за пределы экрана, как сделать возможность прокручивать TextView вниз? 
Мой TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/UpText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
/>
```

Comment: tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" - нужно привязать к родителю или другим элементам и текст поместится, а эту строчку убрать

Comment: можно обернуть TextView ScrollView

Comment: просто добавь атрибут `android:scrollbars = "vertical"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать через xml так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

можно так же как говорил уже [@pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff) добавить атрибут:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

и в активности дальше нужно добавить:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Вот еще способ как программно проскроллить:

```
mTextStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID);
mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.SCROLLER_ID);

private void scrollToBottom()
{
    mScrollView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mTextStatus.getBottom());
        }
    });
}
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748977/making-textview-scrollable-on-android) можно найти разные реализации того что я привел в своем ответе.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/UpText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:maxLines="4" 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
/>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает, количество выводимых строк программа ограничивает ограничивает, но возможности пролистывать не появляется